# Cross Database Queries in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

When making a query from a SQL Server database in Azure to another database in Azure, having configured MASTER KEY, CREDENTIAL, EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE, and EXTERNAL TABLES in the source Azure database, cannot connect and obtain the error message:

> Msg 46823, Level 16, State 1, Line 183
> Error retrieving data from transaccional.database.windows.net.Transfiriendo_IFactura_Colombia_TransfiriendoFaseII.  The underlying error message received was: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)'.

Comment: Just according the error message, you are doing a cross database query between databases in two Azure SQL  Server. Please go to the Azure SQL Server and set the firewall the roles(add your IP to the firewall).

Answer (score 1):

Just according the error message, you are doing a cross database query between databases in two Azure SQL Server.

When we access other Azure SQL Server, we need be add to that database firewall.

Please go to the Azure SQL Server and set the firewall the roles(add your IP to the firewall).

Comment: Thanks Leo Yue, we have fixed the problem with this, thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @dsoler You're welcome. If the answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: hi @dsoler, do you have any other concerns? Did you solve it by adding the firewall?

Comment: Hello @dsoler, didn't hear from you for long time, may I know why don't you mark it as answer? Thanks!